# Laravel 5 Getting the Database Name

Tags: database, laravel-5, eloquent

I wish to have access to the name of the database at runtime, so as a helper I have the following function:

```
function getDatabaseName()
{
  $name = \DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
  return $name;
}
```

but it returns a blank.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a lot simpler:

```
echo env('DB_DATABASE');
```